# Number of solution of $x\cdot (p-1)! \equiv x\pmod {np}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial, congruences

Find number family of solutions of congruence $$x\cdot (p-1)! \equiv x\pmod {np}$$

Where, $p$ is a prime number.

Comment: 1. Show what you've tried, this is not a 'do-my-homework-for-free' service. 2. What does "number family" mean (apart from leaving the sense that you haven't made the tiniest effort to even phrase the question properly)? 3. Use LaTex for mathematical notations. 4. If $p$ is prime, then please bother to mention it. 5. In general, if you're expecting others to make an effort for you, then you should try to persuade them that you've made some effort yourself.

Comment: What is $n$? Arbitrary fixed integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is not stated very well and it's not clear what $n$ is, however we can try by using the Wilson's theorem:
$$(p-1)! \equiv -1\pmod {p}$$ (where $p$ is prime), so
$$(p-1)! \equiv (p-1)\pmod {p}$$
$$x\cdot (p-1)! \equiv x\cdot (p-1)\pmod {p}$$
The second term of the congruence should be $$x\cdot (p-1)=x$$ thus $$p=2$$
With p=2 we obtain $$x \equiv x\pmod {2}$$
and $$x \equiv x\pmod {2n}$$ for any integer $x$ and $n>0$